# Open multiple Word docs with Excel and import data

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to automate a process of appending data from a fillable word document to Excel sheet.
Here is my code:

```
Sub Test()  
Dim txt As String  
Dim objWrd  
Dim objDoc  
Dim objSelection  
Dim varResult As Variant  
Dim msgValue  
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog  
Dim lngCount As Long  
Dim fNames As New Collection  
Dim rng As Range  
Dim ws As Worksheet  
Dim i As Long, j As Long, RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 2  

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RiskManagement")  

Dim art, adtOcc, atm, acounty, adet, aatt, aloc, bdob, bsex, bvehType, bstblts As String  


Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog( _  
 FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogOpen)  
 With dlgOpen  
 .AllowMultiSelect = True  
 .Show  
End With  

 For lngCount = 1 To dlgOpen.SelectedItems.Count  
fNames.Add (dlgOpen.SelectedItems(lngCount))  
 Next lngCount  


Set objWrd = CreateObject("word.Application")  
For x = 1 To lngCount  
Set objDoc = objWrd.documents.Open(fNames(x))  

Set rng = ws.Range("a" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  
If rng.Row < 2 Then  
Set rng = ws.Range("a2")  
End If  
objWrd.ActiveDocument.Visible = false  
Set objSelection = objWrd.Selection  
art = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("drpIncidentType").Result'<<    
adtOcc = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtDateOccured").Result  
atm = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtTimeOccured").Result  
acounty = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtCountyCode").Result  
adet = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtEmployeeType").Result  
aatt = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("drpAttachment").Result  
aloc = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtLoc").Result  
bdob = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtDriverDOB").Result  
bsex = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("drpDriverGender").Result  
bvehType = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("txtVehicleType").Result  
bstblts = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("drpSeatbelts").Result  

RowCounter = ws.UsedRange.Count + 1  


ws.Cells(RowCounter, 1) = art  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 2) = adtOcc  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 3) = atm  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 4) = acounty  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 5) = adet  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 6) = aatt  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 7) = aloc  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 8) = bdob  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 9) = bsex  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 10) = bvehType  

ws.Cells(RowCounter, 11) = bstblts  



objWrd.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges  
Set objWrd = Nothing  
Next x  





End Sub
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

> Application Defined or Object Defined Error

at the line commented as << in the above code:

```
art = objWrd.ActiveDocument.FormFields("drpIncidentType").Result
```

Any idea as to why I am getting that error and how do I achieve what I am trying to do?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SYA3ub9_PgqrpLzwpl0fDY68My3AxJ5I/view?usp=sharing) is a sample of the report I am working with

**UPDATE:**
This is the updated code:

```
Sub Test()  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  

Dim objWrd As Object  
Dim objDoc As Object  

Dim ws As Worksheet  
Dim lngCount As Long, RowCounter As Long, x As Long  
Dim fNames As New Collection  
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog  

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RiskManagement")  
RowCounter = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row  

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)  
With fd  
 .AllowMultiSelect = True  
 .Show  
 For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count  
  fNames.Add .SelectedItems(lngCount)  
 Next lngCount  
If (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then  

Else  


Set objWrd = CreateObject("word.Application")  

With objWrd  
  .Visible = False  
  If (fNames.Count = 0) Then  
  Exit Sub  
  Else  

Dim WDR As Range  
  For x = 1 To lngCount  
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1  

    Set objDoc = objWrd.Documents.Open(fNames(x))  


    With objDoc  
   MsgBox .Selection.FormFields(1).Result  <<

      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 1) = .ActiveDocument.FormFields("drpIncidentType").DropDown.Value  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 2) = .FormFields("txtDateOccured").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 3) = .FormFields("txtTimeOccured").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 4) = .FormFields("txtCountyCode").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 5) = .FormFields("txtEmployeeType").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 6) = .FormFields("drpAttachment").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 7) = .FormFields("txtLoc").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 8) = .FormFields("txtDriverDOB").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 9) = .FormFields("drpDriverGender").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 10) = .FormFields("txtVehicleType").Result  
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 11) = .FormFields("drpSeatbelts").Result  
      .Close False  
    End With  
  Next  
  .Quit  
  End If  
End With  



objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges  
Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWrd = Nothing  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End If  
End With  
End Sub
```

The only error I get now is:
The Server threw an Exception

It occurs at the first call within objDoc with clause. I have tried a bunch of different variations of Selections and Document and FormFields but it always throws the same error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's not possible to test your code as no one can duplicate your environment.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have uploaded a sample report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this.

```
Sub WordToExcel()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim x As Integer
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim temp As String

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'initialise counter
x = 1
'search for first file in directory
strFolder = "C:\Test\"
strFilename = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc")
'amemd folder name
Do While strFilename <> ""
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strFolder & strFilename)
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 0) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 1) = temp
'etc
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 2) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 3) = temp

wdDoc.Close
x = x + 1
strFilename = Dir
Loop
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @rguy72 I get the error message "The requested member of the collection does not exist" at the temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text   . This is the second line so that means it was able to read the first line, There was no value provided for the second line in the word document. Is there a way to say if no value provided, just enter empty string?

Comment: You could use 'on error resume next' at the top of your script.  This probably isn't the best practice, but the code will continue to run, even after an error is thrown, rather than just shut down completely.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just changed the Field Name to Field Index

Answer (score 2):

You have `Set ObjWrd = Nothing` inside your for loop (all the way at the bottom)

I believe you meant to have `ObjDoc` there

Comment: thanks for identifying that error. Fixed it, but still getting the same error

Comment: @SQLserving If the field `"drpIncidentType"` is a dropdown, you should try `ws.Cells(RowCounter, 1) = .FormFields("drpIncidentType").Dropdown.Value`

Comment: it is a drop down, tried that but still getting same error

Comment: @SQLserving are you sure `drpIncidentType` is the correct name of the field?

Comment: It is a Legacy Form field and that is the name that shows up as Bookmark in properties of that field. I have the sample report linked in the question.

Comment: @SQLserving are you using your original code or the code from Macropod's answer?

Comment: @SQLserving It works on my computer, just needed to change `For x = 1 To lngCount` to `For x = 1 To lngCount - 1`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the errant and unnecessary 'Set ObjWrd = Nothing' inside your loop, your code is a mess. You have numerous unused, undeclared & miss-declared, and unnecessary variables. Moreover, although written for late binding, your code employs Word constants that will only work with early binding. Try:

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim objWrd As Object, objDoc As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngCount As Long, RowCounter As Long, x As Long
Dim fNames As New Collection

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RiskManagement")
RowCounter = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
 .AllowMultiSelect = True
 .Show
 For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
  fNames.Add .SelectedItems(lngCount)
 Next lngCount
End With

Set objWrd = CreateObject("word.Application")
With objWrd
  .Visible = False
  For x = 1 To lngCount
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Set objDoc = objWrd.Documents.Open(fNames(x), , True, False, , , , , , , , False)
    With objDoc
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 1) = .FormFields("drpIncidentType").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 2) = .FormFields("txtDateOccured").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 3) = .FormFields("txtTimeOccured").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 4) = .FormFields("txtCountyCode").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 5) = .FormFields("txtEmployeeType").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 6) = .FormFields("drpAttachment").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 7) = .FormFields("txtLoc").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 8) = .FormFields("txtDriverDOB").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 9) = .FormFields("drpDriverGender").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 10) = .FormFields("txtVehicleType").Result
      ws.Cells(RowCounter, 11) = .FormFields("drpSeatbelts").Result
      .Close False
    End With
  Next
  .Quit
End With
Set objDoc = Nothing: Set objWrd = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error at the same spot, which in your case is ws.Cells(RowCounter, 1) = .FormFields("drpIncidentType").Result

Comment: In that case you need to check that the bookmark named 'drpIncidentType' is correct and that it references a text or dropdown formfield of that name in the document that's throwing the error.

Comment: I checked the references and tried with DropDown as well as just using FormFields(1) to point to the first occurence, but I get "The server threw an Exception"--I have updated the question

Comment: The fault isn't with the code. Maybe you need to repair your Office installation.